# Function from basis to isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let **B**  be set of pairs($X$,$Y$) such that $X$ is an ordered basis for $V$ and $Y$ is an ordered basis for W. Let $dim$V$=n$ and dim$W$=m. Now let **I** be the set of all isomorphisms from Hom($V$,$W$) to the set of matrices of dimension $m×n$ with entries in a field $\mathbb{K}$.

Now define the function $f$ from the set **B** to the set **I** such that $f(X,Y) = M_{XY}$, where $M_{XY}(T)={Y}_[T]_{X}$ for some $T$ in Hom($V$,$W$).

Show that f in not surjective in general and f is not inyective in general.

I think that proving it is not injective is not so difficult, but I really have problems showing that f is not surjective, I tried to build a "nice" isomorphism but my efforts were in vain, so, any ideas?

Comment: Which kind of isomorphisms are the elements of $\mathbf I$?

Comment: Any kind of isomorphism between those two sets

Comment: @Serbitas: That's not an answer: Are they group isomorphisms, ring isomorphisms, merely bijections (the isomorphiams of $\mathbf{Set}$), or what? The word "isomorphism" alone has no meaning until you qualify it with which kind of structure you expect it to preserver (or which category you're working in).

Comment: Sorry, they are isomorphism between vector spaces

Answer (score 1):

Let $V=W=\mathbb R^2$, and consider the $g\in\mathbf I$ such that

$$ g(T) = \begin{pmatrix} a & d \\ b & c \end{pmatrix} \text{ where the matrix of $T:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ is } \begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix} $$

Then, in particular, $g$ sends the *identity* morphism to $({}^1_0\;{}^1_0)$, but no $f(X,Y)$ ever sends the identity transformation to a matrix of rank $1$.